Error while copying Azure Storage table from one Storage to another storage table using Powershell script
Facing Error while copying Azure Storage table from one Storage to another storage table  using Powershell script "InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync'"
#Set Variables to define source and destination values
$sourcestorageaccountname = "stlpttoragetst"
$sourceresourcegroupname = "RG_SUPPLY__ADF_TEST_AUE"
$destinationstorageaccountname = "stlpestorage"
$destinationresourcegroupname = "RG_SUPPLY_DEV_AUE"
$sourcetablename = "DataConfig" 
$desttablename =  "TestTable"

#Get storage account keys
$sourcestorageaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $sourceresourcegroupname -Name $sourcestorageaccountname
$destinationstorageaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $destinationresourcegroupname -Name $destinationstorageaccountname
 
$sourcekey = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$g=="
$destinationkey = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"  

#Function to create CloudTable refernce
function Get-CloudTable {
    param (
        [string]$accountName,
        [string]$accountKey,
        [string]$tableName
    )
    $storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

    #Get Cloud Table Refernce
    $table = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageContext

    return $table
}

#Get Source table and Destination table refernce 
$sourceTable = Get-CloudTable -accountName $sourcestorageaccountname -accountKey $sourcekey -tableName $sourceTablename
$destinationTable = Get-CloudTable -accountName $destinationstorageaccountname -accountKey $destinationkey -tableName $desttablename





#Copy Entity from Source Table to Destination table 
$entities = Get-AzTableRowAll -table $sourcetablename

foreach ($entity in $entities){
#     #Insert or replace entity in destination table
       $insertOperation = Add-AzTableRow -Table $desttablename -partitionKey $entity.PartitionKey -RowKey $entity.RowKey -property $entity.Properties

    }
 Write-Output "Table Copied Completed"


Where are you running the above script?

I try from Powershell ISE also and from powershell 7 ,Even i try from Azure cloud shell where it showing forbidden


Error while copying Azure Storage table from one Storage to another storage table using Powershell script.

You can use the below script to copy table entities from source to another storage account table using PowerShell 7.
You can see the below entities which I stored in source table storage account.
Portal:

Script:
function Copy-AzureTable ($SourceResourceGroupName, $SourceStorageAccountName, $SourceTable, $DestinationResourceGroupName, $DestinationStorageAccountName, $ExistingDestinationTable, $SourceAccountKey, $DestinationAccountKey) {
   
    $SourceCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $SourceAccountKey
    $SourceCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $SourceTable -Context $SourceCtx).CloudTable

    $DestinationCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $DestinationStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $DestinationAccountKey

    # Check if the destination table exists
    try {
        $DestinationCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $ExistingDestinationTable -Context $DestinationCtx).CloudTable
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Destination table '$ExistingDestinationTable' does not exist in the destination storage account."
        return
    }
    
    $SourceCloudTableContent = Get-AzTableRow -Table $SourceCloudTable
    $SourceCloudTableContent | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 500 -Parallel {
        $DestinationCloudTableUpdate = $using:DestinationCloudTable
        $_ | Update-AzTableRow -Table $DestinationCloudTableUpdate
    }
}

Copy-AzureTable "SourceResourceGroup" "SourceStorageAccountName" "SourceTable" "DestinationResourceGroup" "DestinationStorageAccountName" "ExistingDestinationTable" "SourceAccountKey" "DestinationAccountKey"

Output:
Result         : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity
HttpStatusCode : 204
Etag           : W/"datetime'2024-10-17T07%3A29%3A59.4901773Z'"
SessionToken   :
RequestCharge  :
ActivityId     :

Result         : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity
HttpStatusCode : 204
Etag           : W/"datetime'2024-10-17T07%3A29%3A59.7052318Z'"
SessionToken   :
RequestCharge  :
ActivityId     :


Portal:

The above script copied entities from source table storage to destination table storage account.

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
at two place getting this error:
$SourceCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $sourcetablename -Context $SourceCtx).CloudTable
$DestinationCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $destinationstorageaccountname -StorageAccountKey $destinationkey

Check the access keys are malformed or improperly passed, as they are expected to be valid Base64 strings.

$SourceCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $sourcetablename -Context $SourceCtx).CloudTable on ths line getting this erro "An error occurred while sending the request."
while line number 38  $SourceCloudTableContent = Get-AzTableRow -Table $SourceCloudTable and  $_ | Update-AzTableRow -Table $DestinationCloudTableUpdate
throwing Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Table' because it is null now getting this error sharing you my script i modify

Update the question which the code you tried and also paste the error.

Have you tried exact my code?

Hello@venkatesan  Thanks for your assistance finally we are able to debug the error and able to complete our operation.It works

We face error while assigning variable to keys so we hardcoded them for the mean while tested on powershell 7
    az login
    az account set --subscription 444444-44445555555555555-55555555555555
    #Set Variables to define source and destination values
    $sourcestorageaccountname = "stsecurestoragetst"
    $sourceresourcegroupname = "RG_PLANTRANSFORM_ADF_TEST_AUE"
    $destinationstorageaccountname = "stsecurestorage"
    $destinationresourcegroupname = "RG_PLANTRANSFORM_ADF_DEV_AUE"
    $sourcetablename = "DataFactoryPipelineConfig"
    $desttablename = "TestTable"
     
    #Get storage account keys
    $sourcestorageaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $sourceresourcegroupname -Name $sourcestorageaccountname
    $destinationstorageaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $destinationresourcegroupname -Name $destinationstorageaccountname
     
    $sourcekey = "xxxxx"
    $destinationkey = "zxxx"
    #######
    
     
    function Copy-AzureTable ($sourceresourcegroupname, $sourcestorageaccountname, $sourcetablename, $destinationresourcegroupname, $destinationstorageaccountname, $desttablename, $sourcekey, $destinationkey) {
    
       #$SourceCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $sourcestorageaccountname -StorageAccountKey $sourcekey
         $SourceCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "ssecurestoragetst" -StorageAccountKey "KJ7f94f44lF4FZUi7TT7sH2nhuJ/Tfcwr7rPSyjUJKDg=="
         #Write-Host $SourceCtx
        $SourceCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name "DataFactoryPipelineConfig" -Context $SourceCtx).CloudTable
        write-Host $SourceCloudTable
     
        $DestinationCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "stsecurestorage" -StorageAccountKey "OOo5P3Kez9jlEPA/1DC3EYD3yECsnuROW9w=="
     
        # Check if the destination table exists
        try {
            $DestinationCloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name "TestTable" -Context $DestinationCtx).CloudTable
            Write-Host $DestinationCloudTable
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Destination table '$desttablename' does not exist in the destination storage account."
            return
        }
        $SourceCloudTableContent = Get-AzTableRow -Table $SourceCloudTable
        Write-Host $SourceCloudTableContent
        $SourceCloudTableContent | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 500 -Parallel {
            $DestinationCloudTableUpdate = $using:DestinationCloudTable
            $_ | Update-AzTableRow -Table $DestinationCloudTableUpdate
        }
    }
     
    Copy-AzureTable "sourceresourcegroupname" "sourcestorageaccountname" "sourcetablename" "destinationresourcegroupname" "destinationstorageaccountname" "desttablename" "sourcekey" "destinationkey"

